# How to achieve reverse animation on mouse out using keyframes

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

I am trying to add scale up animation on a div.
I tried this using both `transition` and `animation` property.

In case of `transition` you can notice that when hovered out the animation is smoothly reversed. However, this doesn't happen when using `animation` property (the div transitions back to initial width instantly)

Can someone tell me:

1. Why this behaviour in case of `animation` only?
2. How can I achieve the same using `animation` property?

```css
.animations {
  display: flex;
  padding: 80px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f3d2d2, white, #cee5f3);
}
.animations > div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 40px;
  font-family: system-ui;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.animations > p {
  color: black;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.animations .animated-box {
  flex: 2;
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}
.animated-box.scale-up {

}
.animated-box.scale-up:hover {
   animation: scale-up 0.5s ease forwards;
 transform: scale(1);
}
.animated-box.scale-up-with-mouseout {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
.animated-box.scale-up-with-mouseout:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
 
  
@keyframes scale-up {
  100% {transform: scale(1.2)};
  0%{transform: scale(1)};
}
```

```html
<div class="animations">
  <div>
    <div class="animated-box scale-up">Hover me</div>
    <p>Scale up (with keyframes)</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="animated-box scale-up-with-mouseout">Hover me</div>
    <p>Scale up (with transition)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

invert this part only

```
@keyframes scale-up {
  100% {transform: scale(1.2)};
  0%{transform: scale(1)};
}
```

and to fix the animation when mouse out add a new `keyframe`

```
@keyframes scale-down {
  0% {transform: scale(1.2)};
  100%{transform: scale(1)};
}
```

and apply it to the class `.animated-box.scale-up`

```
.animated-box.scale-up {
   animation: scale-down 0.5s ease forwards;
}
```

```css
.animations {
  display: flex;
  padding: 80px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f3d2d2, white, #cee5f3);
}
.animations > div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 40px;
  font-family: system-ui;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.animations > p {
  color: black;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.animations .animated-box {
  flex: 2;
  width: 100%;
  background: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
}
.animated-box.scale-up {
   animation: scale-down 0.5s ease forwards;
}
.animated-box.scale-up:hover {
   animation: scale-up 0.5s ease forwards;

}
.animated-box.scale-up-with-mouseout {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
.animated-box.scale-up-with-mouseout:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
 
  
@keyframes scale-up {
  100% {transform: scale(1.2)};
  0%{transform: scale(1)};
}
  
@keyframes scale-down {
  0% {transform: scale(1.2)};
  100%{transform: scale(1)};
}
```

```html
<div class="animations">
  <div>
    <div class="animated-box scale-up">Hover me</div>
    <p>Scale up (doesn't work)</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="animated-box scale-up-with-mouseout">Hover me</div>
    <p>Scale up (works)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `to fix the animation when mouse out add a new keyframe`
This also fires on initial render too which i don't want